# the square root of complex no. has 2 values, while that of a real no. has one, even when a real no. can be expressed as complex no. whats going on?

Tags: complex-numbers

By square root I mean we are using the radical symbol. Why do we say that a real no has 1 value of square root when a complex one has 2 ?

Comment: How do you define the square root function if your input is complex? How do you define the square root function as a function in general?

Answer (score 1):

A real number, as a complex number has two square roots ($2$ and $-2$ are two square roots of $4$). However, by convention the square root of a real number $x$ is the only **positive** real number $y$ such that $x=y^2$. Such a convention can not be extend to $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{C}$ does not admit any [order relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory).

Comment: In addition to your (+1) answer, I would like to mention to the OP that complex numbers cannot be ordered on a number line, in other words, there is no such thing as a positive or negative complex number, which lies at the crux here.